# Execute text using parameters

Tags: postgresql

I have a query which takes stored query as text form  a table and then run the specific query by user parameter. (in this case the parameter is name)
The query goes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.event_test(strt timestamp without time zone, ende timestamp without time zone, name character varying, world integer, type character varying, type_value integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(user_code character varying, user_nick character varying, alliance character varying, delta bigint)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
stmt text;
           BEGIN
select query   into stmt   from events_queries   where event_name=name  ;
return query execute stmt using strt,ende,world,type,type_value   ;
           END
           $function$
```

When I am running it I get the error:

**Column strt does not exist**

even though I used execute with `using`. 
The function uses the parameter `name` properly and if instead of using execute I write the query itself it goes fine as well.

I have looked at this similar problem :
[Pl/pgSQL there is no parameter $1 in EXECUTE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302098/pl-pgsql-there-is-no-parameter-1-in-execute-statement)

But the problems remains.

Any Idea how to pass the parameters inside my text?

Comment: I do not get the error you say that you see. Since you have a misnamed field in your function ("end" rather than "ende") I don't see how it can. Check you are calling the function you think you are.

Comment: @ Richard Huxton , thx for you mark. I corrected the question.. still the problem remains... it sais it did find the strt column. I am calling the right function... if I do not use execute stmt and write the query inside it works perfectly.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it here. Provide a complete script with dummy tables etc that reproduces the problem.